# Is there a best practice guidance for SignalR error handling in C# (client and server side)?

Tags: c#, .net, error-handling, signalr

I googled around to find some best practice guidance for handling errors within the server business logic and transport them to the client. Compared to WCF where exists FaultException and FaultContract there seems to be no equivalent. But how to transport the error information to the client (e.g. Error-Code) and how to built the API to reflect that?

In case there is no out-of-the-box builtin mechanism to use:

For example, should I wrap up the messages into some envelope containing a field that is filled in case of error?

Should I add an identity field to every call and have a separate Subsription to an Error Message type where I get notifications (containing the identity given with the call) and the client has to map this manually?

```
public Task<IEnumerable<SomeType>> GetSomeThing(IHubProxy hubProxy, int someParam)
{
    try
    {
        // how do we transpor technical and business errors?
        return hubProxy.Invoke<SomeType>("GetSomeThing", someParam);
    }
    catch (SomeException ex)
    {
        // huh? does server side exception is catched here at the client?
    }

    return null;
}

public class SomeEnvelope<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
    public int ErrorCode { get; set; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
}

public Task<IEnumerable<SomeEnvelope<SomeType>>> GetSomeThing(IHubProxy hubProxy, int someParam)
{
    try
    {
        // envelope can be checked for ErrorCode
        return hubProxy.Invoke<SomeEnvelope<SomeType>>("GetSomeThing", someParam);
    }
    catch (SomeException ex)
    {
        // huh? build SomeEnvelope locally at the client now?
    }
}

public Task GetSomeThing(IHubProxy hubProxy, int someParam)
{
    try
    {
        // envelope can be checked for ErrorCode
        hubProxy.On<SomeEnvelope<SomeType>>("GetSomeThing", someParam);
    }
    catch (SomeException ex)
    {
        // huh? build SomeEnvelope locally at the client now?
    }
}

public async Task NotifyAboutSomeThing(Notifier n)
{
    // how to do it here? also envelope?
    this.hubProxy.On<NotifyAboutSomeThingArgs>("NotifyAboutSomeThing", n.OnNotifyAboutSomeThing);

    // by the way... what about the subscription (which is IDisposable)?
}
```

Comment: First using System.Threading.Monitor you need to synchronize the access to the objects and catch the exceptions using AutoResetEvent class

Comment: @HameedSyed: Thx for the info, is there a recipe snippet anywhere (MSDN?)

Comment: I think there should be an already existing way to prefer instead of using AutoResetEvent here... is this really the typical / promoted aproach? I can't believe I have to do it that lowlevel. Maybe envelope aproach?

Comment: If you returned a faulted task from a hub method SignalR server will catch it  and send as an error message over the wire. On the client side this error message will be turned again into an exception (AFAIR HubException) and rethrown when you await your Invoke call. Is it what you are asking?